# How to use Hadoop streaming input parameter for matlab shell script

Tags: matlab, shell, hadoop, stdin, hadoop-streaming

Actually i want to execute my matlab code in hadoop streaming. My doubt is how to use hadoop streaming input parameter value for my matlab input. For example ,

This is my matlab file imreadtest.m (simple coding)

```
rgbImage = imread('/usr/new.jpg');
imwrite(rgbImage,'/usr/OT/testedimage1.jpg');
```

my shell script is

```
#!/bin/sh
matlabbg imreadtest.m -nodisplay
```

Normally this works well in my ubuntu. (Not in hadoop). I have stored these two files in my HDFS using hue. now my matlab script looks like (imrtest.m)

```
rgbImage = imread(STDIN);
imwrite(rgbImage,STDOUT);
```

My shell script is (imrtest.sh).

```
#!/bin/sh
matlabbg imrtest.m -nodisplay
```

I have tried to execute this in hadoop streaming

```
 hadoop@xxx:/usr/local/master/hadoop$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar -mapper /usr/OT/imrtest.sh -file /usr/OT/imrtest.sh -input /usr/OT/testedimage.jpg -output /usr/OT/opt
```

But i got error like this

```
packageJobJar: [/usr/OT/imrtest.sh, /usr/local/master/temp/hadoop- unjar4018041785380098978/] [] /tmp/streamjob7077345699332124679.jar tmpDir=null
14/03/06 15:51:41 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
14/03/06 15:51:41 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
14/03/06 15:51:41 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
14/03/06 15:51:41 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/03/06 15:51:42 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/usr/local/master/temp/mapred/local]
14/03/06 15:51:42 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_201403061205_0015
14/03/06 15:51:42 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
14/03/06 15:51:42 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/local/master/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=slave3:8021 -kill job_201403061205_0015
14/03/06 15:51:42 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://slave3:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201403061205_0015
14/03/06 15:51:43 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
14/03/06 15:52:15 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
14/03/06 15:52:15 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
14/03/06 15:52:15 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/local/master/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=slave3:8021 -kill job_201403061205_0015
14/03/06 15:52:15 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://slave3:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201403061205_0015
14/03/06 15:52:15 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: NA
14/03/06 15:52:15 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
```

Streaming Command Failed!

jobtracker error log for this job is

```
HOST=null
USER=hadoop
HADOOP_USER=null
last Hadoop input: |null|
last tool output: |null|
Date: Thu Mar 06 15:51:51 IST 2014
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:297)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeUTF8(TextInputWriter.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeValue(TextInputWriter.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:110)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.Pipe
   java.io.IOException: log:null
       .
       .
       .
```

Please suggest me how to get input from hadoop streaming input for my matlab script input, Similarly output.

Comment: You specified an output file but your mapper doesn't emit data, try to remove the "-output" option

Comment: The general command line syntax is
    bin/hadoop command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]


    For more details about these options:
    Use $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar build/hadoop-streaming.jar -info

output is must for hadoop streaming. But i want to run my job in hadoop streaming with or without output.